# QTreeWidget Expanding The Width Of Column Header Dynamically C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an application with Qt/c++ that includes a QTreeWidget that has 2 columns. The column headers are "Name:" and "Value:".

I am logging more and more information to the QTreeWidget but when I run the application it opens smaller than the length of many items (Words), inside.

I want to dynamicially expand the column header's width according to the items inside the columns.

I would be really glad if someone could help me.

Comment: @cbuchart That was not the same with my question but it was similar. I should have checked for that question too. Thanks for guiding me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because QTreeWidget inherits QTreeView you can do this for say column index 0:

```
ui->treeWidget->resizeColumnToContents(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,it worked.